# Installing DeepStream SDK on Jetson Nano 4GB-B01 with limited space

Tags: nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, nvidia-docker, deepstream.io, nvidia-deepstream

I have a Jetson Nano 4GB (B01) SOC board and I am running out of space to install the DeepStream SDK.
I want to use DeepStream for video streaming application on my Jetson Nano SOC board, but I need guidance on how to install it .

What are the steps to install DeepStream SDK on the Jetson Nano?